# Collapsing Related Files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio as most of you will have noticed that related file can be collapsed in to one. E.G.

- Form1.cs

  - Form1.Designer.cs

I'm creating a DAL library and will be splitting partial classes in to  several files such as:

- SomeTableClass.cs

  - SomeTableClass.Generated.cs
  - SomeTableClass.SomethingElse.cs

Is there any way in Visual Studio to recognise these file are related to each other an create the collapsible effect?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: For VS 2010 (version 10), use HKCU instead:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046591/visual-studio-2010-related-file-nesting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046591/visual-studio-2010-related-file-nesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my (VisualStudio 2005) system, they are stored in the registry under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles`

For VisualStudio 2008, change the `\8.0\` to `\9.0\`

Note, however, that the GUID in the middle refers to the type of project (VB Console, C# Web, etc) it is.  You may have to poke around to find the right one for you.

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2008, there is also a project file-level way to do this via the `DependentUpon` tag.  You would edit your project file to look like this:

```
<Compile Include="SomeTableClass.cs" />
<Compile Include="SomeTableClass.Generated.cs">
    <DependentUpon>SomeTableClass.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: True but if you have a lot of files to collapse - this could take a while ;) - Cheers anyway

Answer (score 2):

In my Windows 7 x64 environment, the registry keys for Visual Studio 2008 Professional are located here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles`

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2012, they are to be found in the `HKCU`, i.e.:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles`

Comment: sadly I have not managed to use the .ts with .js. It seems it does not work for all extensions this way

Answer (score 2):

A useful VS plugin has since popped up that takes care of this problem for me: [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45)

Answer (score 2):

By Visual Studio 2022 there is a feature named, "File nesting" which can be toggled from the Solution Explorer toolbar button.