# Visual Studio 2010 related file nesting

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2008 you could add registry entries so that X.aspx.js or X.aspx.css would show up as nested underneath X.aspx.  I would use the following registry file to accomplish this for web sites as well as web apps:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.js]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.css]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
".designer.cs"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
```

I replaced 9.0 with 10.0 and applied the changes to my registry, but that's didn't do it.  I have restarted VS as well as my computer, and I've also tried readding the files in question to my web project. I searched around online and found a few people asking about the same thing but no definite solution ([link1](http://forums.asp.net/p/1048008/2104993.aspx) [link2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/5ec8d8cd-a118-4380-bf67-b4b72fc85ea4)).

Does anyone know how to get files to nest in 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like VS2010 settings are per "user" and not "per machine"
D'oh!

So search in the HKEY_USERS until you'll find your user's settings.

Answer (score 4):

This post applies to **VISUAL STUDIO 2010** only.

You will find below the registry entries for VB and C# (apps and web sites). It will nest xxx.xxx.js under the related file as per illustration below.

[image: Javascript nesting - Solution Explorer]

### Important

- You must add the suffix *.aspx.js, otherwise it won't work.
- Existing script files in your project will not be nested under the related file. It only applies to new script files added after the registry changes.

### To change the Registry

- Highlight the entire content from the grey area below, copy and paste into Notepad.
- Save the file to your desktop as **VSRegistry.reg**, then close Notepad.
- Right-click **VSRegistry.reg** on your desktop, then choose **Merge** from the popup menu.
- Voila', you can now launch Visual Studio 2010 and try adding a new javascript file.

---

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx]
"RelationType"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.cs]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.css]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.js]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.vb]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.xml]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.xslt]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{F184B08F-C81C-45f6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}\RelatedFiles\.ascx]
".designer.vb"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.ascx]
".designer.cs"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
"RelationType"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.cs]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.css]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.js]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.vb]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.xml]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.xslt]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{F184B08F-C81C-45f6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
".designer.vb"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
".designer.cs"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the registry file if anyone wants it. It'll nest files for C# web apps and web sites. Shut down all instances of VS before importing.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx]
"RelationType"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.cs]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.css]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.js]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.vb]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.xml]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.ascx\.xslt]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.ascx]
".designer.cs"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
"RelationType"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.cs]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.css]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.js]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.vb]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.xml]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{E24C65DC-7377-472b-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}\RelatedFiles\.aspx\.xslt]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Projects\{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\RelatedFiles\.aspx]
".designer.cs"=dword:00000002
".cs"=dword:00000002
".js"=dword:00000002
".css"=dword:00000002
".xslt"=dword:00000002
".xml"=dword:00000002
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is also some manual editing you can do to the project XML file to achieve this.

Example:

```
<Content Include="Default.js">
    <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

Source: http://davefancher.com/2012/02/23/nesting-files-in-visual-studio/