# Collapsing related razor items in visual studio?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2022

**Goal** - I am trying to change the visual studio solution explorer collapse settings, so that files with extensions such as .razor.css are collapsed under their 'parent' file so to speak.

**Expected** - My laptop environment does this automatically, I simply name the file (i.e. Index.razor Index.razor.css) and the situation resolves itself without any input from me.

[image: Laptop environment showing collapsible structure.]

**Actual** - My desktop environment does not do this, for some reason it lists all the files consecutively, only collapsing from the folders.

[image: Desktop environment showing no collapsibility.]

I have, no doubt, unchecked a box somewhere to get myself into this mess. I would rather not attempt to fix the problem with explicit entries in my .csproj or registry as recommended [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337406/collapsing-related-files-in-visual-studio), unless I absolutely must.

If anyone knows a way to control or edit this behaviour in Visual Studio Community 2022 then please do let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [File Nesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022).  It is customizable, but in web projects should also have smarter defaults for most of the file types shown.

For non-web projects, you may need to enable it manually.  See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/7939) for details, but the TL;DR is to add this to your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNesting" />
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNestingFeatureEnabled" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you're in a web project or have applied the workaround, I'd first check that the feature hasn't been accidentally disabled.  If it's enabled and still not working, consider filing a bug via the VS Feedback tool or via the GitHub repo mentioned above so the feature team can follow up with you directly.

Comment: Lifesaver mate, it's been doing my head in for days, turns out I had the toggle turned off at the top of the solution explorer on my desktop. Appreciate the help!